# Low classification accuracy for statistically different features

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, supervised-learning, accuracy

I am a little bit confused about the machine learning outcomes on my dataset. I would be grateful if anyone can enlighten me on this:

When features are statistically different between two groups, shouldn't the machine learning  able to predict the right class with a reasonable accuracy? The data consists of 9 features where 8 of them were significantly different between the groups (two tailed independent ttest). Total observations were 71 (30 and 41). However, the machine learning were only able to produce around 65% classification accuracy (10 fold cross validation). I have used SVM with RBF kernel, kNN, Random Forest, and Naive Bayes. My question is, is it normal? Is it possible to get higher classification accuracy when the features were not significantly different between the groups? Thanks.

Comment: It is not the significant p-value which matters here but rather the difference itself, the effect size.

Comment: Thanks very much ttnphns. I was overlooking the effect size. The Hedge's g were more than 0.7 for each features (except one which was not significant, i.e., 0.07. However, the accuracy only increased to ~67% if I remove it.) I think these effect sizes are within the moderate range, arent they?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that proportional 'classified' correctly is an arbitrary discontinuous improper accuracy scoring rule.  Don't trust anything you learn from it.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why, or at least give some alternatives?

Comment: As log-likelihood and related Bayesian measures are the ideal optimality criteria, it is best to use log-likelihood-based measures to study predictive information.  This includes generalized $R^2$.  The Brier score (quadratic accuracy score) is also an excellent choice if $Y$ is binary, followed by the concordance probability ($c$-index = AUROC).  Improper scoring rules are optimized by choosing the wrong features and wrong model.  I have an example where adding a powerful variable makes the proportion classified correctly _decrease_.

Comment: Your response and looking at your previous answers has been very enlightening for me. I just have one question.. you make a great point about classification being unnecessary and how ROC curves themselves are not that useful. But how does the AUROC escape this criticism, being a product of the ROC curve?

Comment: The fact that a nice index such as the concordance probability happens to equal the area under the ROC curve is just an unfortunate coincidence.  I like the $c$-index in spite of it equaling the area.  The $c$-index has a much simpler and cleaner interpretation than ROC and does not even tempt one to consider cutpoints.

Comment: Thanks very much Frank & Matthew. I really appreciate your help. Would you please be kind to provide me a link for these? Basically I have 3 classes. I used one vs one for SVM (slightly better than one vs all) where the rests can handle multi classes. Most of the literatures in my field (Biomechanics) were reported accuracy, auc, and F-score. However, I was mainly puzzled by the fact that the overall classification accuracies were less than 70%, although the features were significantly different (p<0.001)! Using a different dataset, I got ~90% overall accuracy for similar effect size.

Comment: I'm not clear why you keep referring to 'accuracy' when you mean a very restricted type of accuracy.  Note that you can have poor predictive discrimination even with highly significant predictors, but you can also have useful predictive discrimination when the over-simplified 'accuracy' score is not very impressive.  Then there is the utter and complete arbitrariness of the cutoff for predicted probabilities needed to compute 'accuracy'.